# Apex Trigger (should be simple)

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

I am trying to write a trigger that will copy a field on a custom object from one field to another during the save or when things have changed.  So the custom object is McLabs_Property__c, the field I want to update is the standard field Name, I would like to update this name with the custom field McLabs_Property_Name__c

```
trigger <name> on McLabs2__Property__c (before insert, before update) 
{    
    for (McLabs2__Property__c a:trigger.new)
    { 
        a.name__r = a.McLabs2_Property_Name__c;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The standard Name field API is just `Name`, not `Name__r`.  Having the suffix __r denotes that a *custom* field is being used as a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using a field update workflow rule.